# How can I see in Fiddler if an HTTP request being sent has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, cors, fiddler

I have looked at all the headers. As far as I know my application code should be sending it out for Ajax calls but I cannot see any header in Fiddler saying anything like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Is there a way for me to check this with Fiddler and if so where should I be looking?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx to get a better understanding of why this is a RESPONSE header, not a REQUEST header.

Answer (score 2):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Have you been looking at the response headers in Fiddler?

Comment: I am bit confused here. I thought this was the header that a browser sends out to tell the server that it's okay to get data back from that server even though it is not the same URL that was used to get the page. My application is sending out /Token for authentication and Chome is complaining that this header is not present.

Comment: First, your AJAX call needs to be cross-domain. Second, if so, the browser will send an OPTIONS request instead of a POST, PUT, etc first (this is a pre-flight request), with the Origin: header. The server should respond with Access-Control-Allow-* response headers